# After I add UIImageView to a UIWindow of an external screen, I have to rotate it why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwindow, uiscreen

I've seen this now in a few examples of adding support for an external screen on the iPad 1.
They always add a CGAffineTransformRotate that is +/- 90 degrees.
But why, is my question. Why is an image-view not horizontal when I add it to a window?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't had to rotate any image views on external displays. Is the nib setup in landscape mode?

Comment: It was, but when I switched it to landscape there was no difference.